# What is the time complexity when accessing an array element in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am aware that in statically typed languages such as C/C++, accessing an array element takes O(1). What would be the case for ruby?

Let's say I have an array `a = [1, "Hello", true]`. What would be the time complexity if I have to access `a[1]`

Comment: @mudasobwa: Not a duplicate. The linked question is about `Array#length`, not `Array#[]`. As for the question : `a[1]` is O(1), `a.index("Hello")` is O(n).

Comment: @EricDuminil the linked answer covers the main aspect: there in no notion of “time complexity of a method in ruby” due to fairly different ruby implementations, like MRI, JRuby etc. The question as it stated has no answer (`O(N)` is misleading,) and from this point of view is’s a duplicate.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'd argue that Ruby is MRI unless otherwise stated, even though it's not technically correct. It probably is for 99.9% of every Ruby questions on SO.